# extjs spacing issue in window with 2 items

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have an extjs window object like this:

```
win = new Ext.Window({
layout:'fit', 
title: '<spring:message code="title.alertDetails" />',
autoDestroy: true,
autoScroll: true,
width:600,
height:400,
closable:false,
plain: true,
items: [detailGrid,msgDetailsPanel],
buttons: [{
text: '<spring:message code="label.button.close" />',
handler: function(){
win.hide(this);
}
}]
});
```

There are 2 items: detailGrid(GridPanel) and msgDetailsPanel(Ext.ux.ManagedIFrame.Panel).

Now when the window renders, the detailGrid takes up a lot of vertical space even if the grid has only 1 item and i need to scroll down to see the msgDetailsPanel. How can i make these 2 items auto adjust the size based on their contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the `autoHeight : true` for both the `grid` and the `ManagerIFramePanel` and remove the `height` property of both of them. Then the `grid` and the `panel` will take up only as much space as required by their `child items` or `grid rows`.

Answer (score 1):

i think best way is:

1. use border `layout` for win; `center` region for grid and `south` for panel.
2. set panel `height = win.height - grid.getStore().getCount() * 25 - 30;`
3. set `split = true` for panel

Answer (score 0):

The reason is actually because you have layout: 'fit' set on the window itself, which is supposed to support just a single item spanning the whole height and width of the panel. Use layout: 'auto', or maybe 'vbox' / 'hbox'.